# Vim set scrolloff=one-paragraph

Tags: vim, scrolling

I use `scrolloff` to see some context around the line I'm working on. What I really care is that context to be visible, not arbitrary number of lines.

Is such thing possibile (may be scriptable) in vim?

To illustrate, suppose I jump down somewhere to the following paragraph:

```
                    *:pta* *:ptag*
:pta[g][!] [tagname]
        Does ":tag[!] [tagname]" and shows the found tag in a
        "Preview" window without changing the current buffer or cursor
        position.  If a "Preview" window already exists, it is re-used
        (like a help window is).  If a new one is opened,
        'previewheight' is used for the height of the window.   See
        also |:tag|.
        See below for an example. |CursorHold-example|
        Small difference from |:tag|: When [tagname] is equal to the
        already displayed tag, the position in the matching tag list
        is not reset.  This makes the CursorHold example work after a
        |:ptnext|.
```

The ideal scroll would show me entire paragraph (assuming it fits in the screen). To ensure this, I need at least `scrolloff=15` for this case.

Comment: Can you please be more precise? What aspect of `'scrolloff'` is bothering you? How would you determine the "context" instead?